# Nested Lists in Slim-lang

Tags: slim-lang

I'm trying to nest a second `ul` in a list item in Slim-lang like so:

```
div.row
        ul.dropdown
            li Dropdown Option 1
                ul
                    li Dropdown Option 2
                    li Dropdown Option 3
```

Expected outcome was this:

```
<div class="row">
  <ul class="dropdown">
    <li>Dropdown Option 1</li>
      <ul>
        <li>Dropdown Option 2</li>
        <li>Dropdown Option 3</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Received output was:

```
<div class="row">
  <ul class="dropdown">
    <li>Dropdown Option 1 ul li Dropdown Option 2 li Dropdown Option 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Do I simply have an error or is this a problem with slim-lang?

Answer (score 4):

For this to work the text you have on the `li Dropdown Option 1` needs to be moved to it's own line (not inline).  This should work (note the 3rd and 4th lines):

```
div.row
        ul.dropdown
            li 
              | Dropdown Option 1
                ul
                    li Dropdown Option 2
                    li Dropdown Option 33
```

Comment: The indentation in this example did not work for me.  For this to work the second 'ul' needed to be at the same indentation level as the '|' above it.

Answer (score 2):

While this wasn't exactly the way I *wanted* to solve the problem I had, I was able to get Slim to compile the nested elements like I wanted to by breaking into normal HTML:

```
div.row
    ul.dropdown
        <li>Dropdown Option 1
            ul
                li Dropdown Option 2
                li Dropdown Option 3
```

If anyone has some insight to why this worked/why the other implementation wasn't working, I'd love to know (or if my original problem wasn't the expected behavior -- if so, I'll open an issue on their Github repo).

Comment: In a new version, you can rid of div tag